# Watson-discovery and Nodejs: Not getting expected answer for my query

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'm currently working on an app with Watson-assistant and Watson-discovery and recently came to a problem. Whenever I make a query to my Watson-discovery collection, it interprets the query right, but within the passages there are always some that contain metadata or document format code.

I want to filter those out since I will be showing the user the response mostly as it comes from discovery.

Here's my code for querying:

```
 function queryDiscovery(query){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    discovery.query({
      environment_id: environment,
      collection_id: collection,
      configuration_id: configuration,
      natural_language_query: query,
      passages: true,
      count: 3,
    }, (err, data) => {
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      } else {
        const {results} = data;
        resolve(data);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

And here's the kind of responses i'm talking about:

```
{
"matching_results": 1,
"session_token": "1_uy3Xpn0Xbw8XEEN4im2fffLxPA",
"passages": [
    {
        "document_id": "906e52b7e1144ab800c955d4d76f4711",
        "passage_score": 7.251949122793696,
        "passage_text": "Microsoft Word - Diabetes tipo 2 Guines en ESPANOL.docx\n\nGuiones Diabetes Tipo 2 1.1 ¿Qué es la diabetes?\n\n• ¿Qué es?\n\nLa diabetes es una enfermedad de larga evolución. Puede provocar problemas",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 193,
        "field": "text"
    },
    {
        "document_id": "906e52b7e1144ab800c955d4d76f4711",
        "passage_score": 6.680067228882112,
        "passage_text": "content=\"24\" name=\"numPages\"/><title>Microsoft Word - Diabetes tipo 2 Guines en ESPANOL.docx</title></head>\n<body><h3><p>Guiones Diabetes Tipo 2 1.1 ¿Qué es la diabetes? </p></h3><p><b>•</b><b> </b>¿Qué es?",
        "start_offset": 197,
        "end_offset": 403,
        "field": "html"
    },.....
```

As you can see, the passage text contains lots of document format code that i don't really want.

There's not much documentation of nodejs+discovery and what i've found wasn't really too helpful. I don't know if the PDF file I uploaded has some kind of wrong format or if I have to configure Discovery in some other way or if it is something different maybe.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect? is it correct the format and spaces of PDF?

Comment: I was actually expecting for plain text, without format. Yes, the format is correct accordingly to the PDF file.